# How to convert an image from color to black and white (grayscale) in Java

Tags: java, image

I just want to convert this color image to black and white but I don't know how to do this.  I just know how to get pixel.  Can you help me?

```
    private BufferedImage image;
    private int[][]rgbValue;       

    public void setRgbValue(BufferedImage image){
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        rgbValue = new int[width*height][3];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<width ; i++){
            for(int j=0 ; j<height ; j++){
                int color = image.getRGB(i, j);
                int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
                int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
                int blue = (color & 0x000000ff);
                rgbValue[counter][0] = red;
                rgbValue[counter][1] = green;
                rgbValue[counter][2] = blue;
                counter++;           
            }        
        }
    }
```

How do I combine that with this code?

```
  temp = red;
  red = green;
  green = blue;
  blue = temp;
  temp = 0;
  rgb[i] = ((red << 16)) + ((green << 8 )) + (blue );
  if(rgb[i] <= 0x670000){
      rgb[i] = 0x000000;
  } else { 
      rgb[i] = 0xffffff;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use Java2D [ColorConvertOp.filter(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html#filter%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) to convert colors of BufferedImage with specified [ColorSpace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/color/ColorSpace.html).

```
BufferedImage bi = null; //Your BufferedImage goes here. null for compiler
ColorConvertOp op = 
    new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);
op.filter(bi, bi);
```

Comment: If I miss this stack item some how, it may be its like I miss world war 2 being an soldier on that day. Thanks.

Comment: This code is not converting the file to black and white. Also, it is increasing the file size to 10 folds. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://spyrestudios.com/html5-canvas-image-effects-black-white/

Comment: OP didn't mention javascript / outputting to a webbrowser